# inserting data from .csv to postgres database

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I'm trying to instert data from .csv file to a Postgres database.

I've tried this:

```
COPY valutu_kursi FROM E'C:\Users\Maris\Downloads\exchangeRates';
```

I get error all the time- "Invalid unicode escape"

How can I make this work?

Comment: I have a déjà vu, I have seen exactly the same question somewhere... And .cvs import has been answered may times here.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below and see

```
COPY valutu_kursi FROM E'C:\\Users\\Maris\\Downloads\\exchangeRates.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Taken from [invalid unicode escape](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4082.1286556109@sss.pgh.pa.us)

> The issue is that Postgres interprets the back slashes in the path
>   name as escapes and errors out with "invalid unicode escape".
>
> You can double the backslashes ('C:\Users...') or you can turn on
>   standard_conforming_strings.  The latter is best done only with
>   considerable testing, though, because it's likely to break anything
>   that knows backslashes are special.