# How to fix invalid Unicode escape in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to import data from excel CSV file to postgreSQL table, I'm using the below query to copy the data into table, however I'm receiving error. Please help.

Query:

```
COPY Table_name FROM 'Path\File_Name.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR:  invalid Unicode escape
```

Comment: Welcome to the forum. try to search for older posts first.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792117/inserting-data-from-csv-to-postgres-database

Comment: What is the version and the setting of `standard_conforming_strings`? Depending on the answer, this question may be a duplicate of the above.